# Disabling changes by dark mode settings and plugins

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have designed a website (in dark theme), and plugins like 'dark reader' and in-built night mode of kiwi browser (Mobile) is Changing the colors of some elements (thus making them invisible), and removing gradient effcts.

Is there any way to avoid those changes?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem. For instance, could you provide screenshots of the website with/without dark mode, and specify what elements are being modified?

Answer (score 0):

This is merely speculative, and needs further research that I leave to you, but you may try to hook on some CSS rule that is known to be altered by the plugins, and check via JS whether it's altered. If you detect that change, you may politely warn your user to disable the plugin you've detected. Dark Reader has a whitelist feature to disable it in some websites, most of the plugins have this feature. As said, this is an untested suggestion.

For Kiwi Browser, you might as well detect user agent and specifically warn the users of this browser.

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, there is a built-in [CSS media selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) slector for that exact thing:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .invisible-in-dark {
    background:#fff !important;
  }
}
```

I don't know how well it works from plugins, but I think it worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I realized that by marking a css property as !important, All changes added by external plugins would be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that dark mode plugins add properties to existing color scheme of script in order to convert the light theme to dark.

Now, if you want to prevent some properties from getting changed by plugin, you can mark it as !important. that way, your property will override any further changes.